# Get node values and attributes as an array using xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Is there any way to get all attributes and its values as an array.
Here I have a node

`<vehicle wheels="four" color="red"/>`

what i need is to get an array like

`$vehicle = array("wheels" => "four", "color" => "red");`

Comment: what do you use to parse the XML, SimpleXML, DOMXPath/DOMDocument, sth else?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `SimpleXMLElement` parsing.

```
$xml = '<vehicle wheels="four" color="red"/>';

$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$array = current($x->attributes());
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using `attributes` property.

Here is the code

```
foreach ($vehicle->attributes as $attribName => $attribute_node)
{
    $array[$attribName] = $attribute_node->nodeValue;
}
```

The $array will produce what is expecting...